# How can I add a array as a property with the following syntax?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var Items = {
    FormVariables: function()
    {
        if (this.array === 'undefined')
        {
           this.array = [];
        }
        return this.array;
    }
};
```

This was my attempt at it and I get an error of it being undefined. Can I even have variables within Items scope like I am attempting. If so, what does the syntax look like?

I am only asking if this can be done using the `var variableName = {}` syntax.

EDIT:

Accessing it

```
    var formVars = new Array();
    formVars.push('[');
    for (var item in gd["FormVariables"])
    {
        formVars.push('"' + item + '":"' + gd["FormVariables"][item] + '"');
    }
    formVars.push(']');
```

The real goal here is to take all these items and convert it to a JSON array of key/value pairs

Comment: what error message states? i tried to run your code and it works ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `[]`. `[]` is a shortcut for `new Array`, just like `{}` is for `new Object`.

```
this.array = [];
```

By the way, there are no 'compiler errors' since JavaScript is not a compiled language but an interpreted one.

Also, your checking does not make much sense. You'd probably want:

```
if (typeof this.array === 'undefined')
```

since `typeof` returns a string. Checking for the string `'undefined'` is not the same as checking for 'real' `undefined`. For the string, it must have been set explicitly to those characters, which is almost never the case.

Comment: I originally tried this. The interpreted error I received though was because I didn't understand how to access the array using this syntax. Maybe you can shed light on an easier approach, I'll post how this all looks

Comment: @Matthew Cox: It seems to work already; could you tell me what I am missing? http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/3MLzH/

Comment: I wanted to include the key as well, which that code was missing. At this point, it appears that you are correct, the updated version I posted works now.

Comment: @Matthew Cox: Great you solved it, but you are now populating an array with `key:value` strings, and a leading `[` and trailing `]`. It may just be what you want, but arrays do not have `key:value` pairs, and remember that you're not building a string but an array. If you want to get the JSON of an object, I think you're making it a little complicated with a custom function.

Comment: @primvdb Yes, I tried to keep the scope of the question as limited as possible. The real goal was to be able to pass a unknown number of custom parameters to an js control on the page that when posting to the server (ASP.NET MVC) would detect and construct the proper structure. The real thing I took away from this posting is how to access it properly. Once you had shown me that syntax would work then I knew it must be an issue with how I was accessing it.